# How to make a Flat UI design with android

Tags: android, layout, ui-design

I've made numerous types of android layouts, however, I had never tried to make a flat UI design like in windows 8 for android.

I want to try to make a UI like windows 8 design in android but I'm having trouble choosing which layout should I use. Is it better to use GridLayout? Or are there some other options for it ? I dont see so much tutorial that is useful for flat ui design's for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a tile layout, you can refer to this project: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

However, Android has its own 'flat UI design' called 'material design'

For more information, you can refer to the following links

http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

http://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html